# $G=(I_{k}|A)$ is a generator matrix of $\mathcal{C}$ iff $H=(-A^{T}|I_{n-k})$ is a control matrix of $\mathcal{C}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, coding-theory

I am trying to prove that, ''given a $\mathcal{C}$ $[n,k,d]$-linear code, $G=(I_{k}|A)$ is a generator matrix of $\mathcal{C}$ iff $H=(-A^{T}|I_{n-k})$ is a control matrix of $\mathcal{C}$''.

Firstly, I have supposed that $G=(I_{k}|A)$ is a generator matrix of $\mathcal{C}$; we name the columns of $A$ as $a_{1},a_{2},..,a_{n-k}$; if $x=(x_{1},...,x_{k})\in\mathbb{F}_{q}^{k}$, I can codify this into a word of the code by taking the generator matrix and multiplying it this way: $xG=(x_{1},...,x_{k},x\cdot a_{1},...,x\cdot a_{n-k})\in\mathcal{C}$, where $\cdot$ is the dot product of two vectors. I also know the following result:

> $H$ is a control matrix of $\mathcal{C}$ if the following holds: $x\in\mathcal{C}$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $Hx^{T}=(0,...,0)^{T}$

So, If I show $H(x_{1},...,x_{k},x\cdot a_{1},...,x\cdot a_{n-k})^{T}=(0,...,0)^{T}$, I would have show that $x\in\mathcal{C}$ $\Rightarrow$ $Hx^{T}=(0,...,0)^{T}$; this is very easy to show taking on account how $H$ is constructed.

For the other direction, I would have to show that $Hx^{T}=(0,..,0)^{T}$ has, as a system of equations, as solutions all the words of the code... Here I get stucked.

Secondly, I would have to prove that, assuming $H=(-A^{T}|I_{n-k})$ is a control matrix of $\mathcal{C}$, $G=(I_{k}|A)$ is a generator matrix of $\mathcal{C}$. For this I suppose I would have to solve the system $Hx^{T}=(0,...,0)^{T}$ (which, by hipothesis I know has as solutions the words of the code), and then show that each of that words can be generated by $G$, i.e., that, given a code word, I can find a vector in $\mathbb{F}_{q}^{k}$ such that the product of that vector by $G$ is the code word firstly given. Nevertheless I am not sure this is the best approach...

Any help, guidance, or anything will be very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. What you wish to show is that the codes defined by $G$ and $H$ are the same, i.e.,

$$ \{ c \in \mathbb{F}_q^n: c=uG, u \in \mathbb{F}_q^k \} = \{ c \in \mathbb{F}_q^n: cH^\mathrm{T}=0\}. $$

Denote the left set by $\mathcal{G}$ and the right one by $\mathcal{H}$.

You have already proven that $\mathcal{G} \subseteq \mathcal{H}$. Since $c\in\mathcal{G}$, it follows that $c = uG$ for some $u\in \mathbb{F}_q^k$ and thus $cH^\mathrm{T}= uGH^\mathrm{T}= u(A-A)= 0$ by definition of the matrices $G$ and $H$.

For the other direction $\mathcal{H} \subseteq \mathcal{G}$, we split the codeword into two parts, $c=(d,e)$, $d \in \mathbb{F}_q^k$, $e \in \mathbb{F}_q^{n-k}$. Observe that with this notation, $cH^\mathrm{T}=0 \Leftrightarrow -dA+e=0 \Leftrightarrow dA = e$. Thus, if we set $u=d$, we obtain
$$ uG = (d,dA) = (d,e), $$
which proves that we can find a vector $u$ that generates $c$ and thus $\mathcal{H} \subseteq \mathcal{G}$.

Comment: Ok! Got it, thanks a lot!